# Product Block not display in Order summary in Magento 2.2.2 checkout

Tags: magento2, blocks, onepage-checkout, custom-options, products

I have recently check my site in IE browser and notice there are no display the product block in order summary block. I added 2 custom attribute in order summary block which is work good in chrome, safari, and other browser issue are only with IE 11.

[image]

Can anyone help to please.

Thanks.

Comment: please check console logs

Comment: there are no error in console.

Comment: can you share your URL?

Comment: give me your email

Comment: you can get it from here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/66125/kunj?tab=profile

Comment: check mail please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78410/discussion-between-kunj-and-ajay-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion, your JS file content should be like this:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
        },
        /**
         * @param {Object} quoteItem
         * @return {String}
         */

        quoteItemData: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
        },
        getValue: function(quoteItem) {
            return quoteItem.name;
        },
        getItemTag: function(quoteItem) {
            var itemProduct = this.getItemProduct(quoteItem.item_id);
            return itemProduct.new;
        },
        getItemProduct: function(item_id) {
            var itemElement = null;
            _.each(this.quoteItemData, function(element, index) {
                if (element.item_id == item_id) {
                    itemElement = element;
                }
            });
            return itemElement;
        }
    });
});
```